# Creating a unknown data type array into a structure?

Tags: c++

I have a structure that I used to populate Class Structures with values:

```
MyType structMy[] =
{
  { START,  INTEGER_TYPE, 3, (void *)&classStart->statusStart.set    },
  { STABLE, CHAR_TYPE,    5, (void *)&classtStable->statusStable.set },
  { STOP,   DOUBLE_TYPE,  1, (void *)&classStop->statusStop.set      }
}
```

But for testing and validation I want to add test cases to the structure: some values which depend on the defined data type per line and number of values.

But because of the structure setup and 1 value or an array, I think I need a (void*). But the compiler doesn't like it.  What can I do to write an array into a structure where data types can change?

```
MyType structMy[] =
{
  { START,  INTEGER_TYPE, 3,  (void*){0, 1, 2}                 },
  { STABLE, CHAR_TYPE,    5,  (void*){'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'} },
  { STOP,   DOUBLE_TYPE,  1,  (void*){2.4}                     }
}
```

Comment: Is this what Google translate does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler wants pointers there, so try declaring the data elsewhere:

```
int is[] = {0, 1, 2};
char cs[] = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'};
double ds[] = {2.4};

MyType structMy[] =
{
     {START, INTEGER_TYPE, 3,  (void*)is },
     {STABLE, CHAR_TYPE, 5,  (void*)cs },
     {STOP, DOUBLE_TYPE, 1,  (void*)ds }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By telling the compiler what type to expect, it can be done like this:

```
MyType structMy[] =
{
   { START,  INTEGER_TYPE, 3,  (void*)(int[]){0, 1, 2}                  },
   { STABLE, CHAR_TYPE,    5,  (void*)(char[]){'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'} },
   { STOP,   DOUBLE_TYPE,  1,  (void*)(double[]){2.4}                   }
}
```